# DevServer keeps shutting down before starting

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, cypress, webpack-dev-server, cypress-component-test-runner

Whenever I run `npx cypress open-ct` my dev-server fails to start.

```
[@cypress/webpack-dev-server]: removing HtmlWebpackPlugin from configuration.
[@cypress/webpack-dev-server]: removing HtmlPwaPlugin from configuration.
[@cypress/webpack-dev-server]: removing PreloadPlugin from configuration.
[@cypress/webpack-dev-server]: removing PreloadPlugin from configuration.
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Gracefully shutting down. To force exit, press ^C again. Please wait...
```

I've tried setting `DEBUG=*` within .env, but nothing is thrown, so I assume an issue is with `Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit`.

I followed the guide from cypress composer test doc and composer tests used to run, but something happened for this to stop from working. I am running this on MacBook.

I have the following components:

- "cypress": "^9.1.1"
- "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0"
- "@cypress/vue": "^2.2.3"
- "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running through the docs and debugging webpack dev server, I've learned that `SIGTERM` exit signal is called, which is why shut down kicks in. A bit more tracing and I noticed that node version needs to be upgraded for everything to work.

Originally I was running node `10.23.0`. After upgrade to `v12` everything worked fine.